# How do I add blurry colour to CALayer() as this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to achieve something as this:
[image]

However I am getting this:
[image]

Code I am using:

```
let border = CALayer()
border.backgroundColor = UIColor.viewShadowGray().cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bottomView.frame.size.width, height: 2)
bottomView.layer.addSublayer(border)

    class func viewShadowGray() -> UIColor
    {
        return UIColor(red: 177.0/255.0, green: 177.0/255.0, blue: 179.0/255.0, alpha: 0.7)

    }
```

Comment: That’s just the shadow on the CALayer. Just type layer.shadow and you will see all the auto complete options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a shadow with UIBezierPath something like as below. 
You may need to vary opacity (`layer?.shadowOpacity = 0.80`) and shadow radius (`layer?.shadowRadius = 3.0`) to match your requirement  .

```
func addShadow(to view: UIView?) {
    //Adds a shadow to view
    let layer: CALayer? = view?.layer
    layer?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    layer?.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer?.shadowRadius = 3.0
    layer?.shadowOpacity = 0.80
    layer?.shadowPath = (UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: layer?.bounds.origin.x ?? 0.0, y: layer?.bounds.origin.y ?? 0.0, width: layer?.bounds.size.width ?? 0.0, height: (layer?.bounds.size.height ?? 0.0) + 1))).cgPath
}
```